# Time (CLR Timespan) column using EF4.1 Code-First approach and SqlCe 4.0

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce-4

I'be been trying to map a Timespan property to a SqlCe 4.0 database using EntityFramework 4.1 Code-First approach, and of course I'm getting a NotSupportedException saying there's no store corresponding EDM type 'Time' and CLR type 'Timespan'.

I was already expecting this, but, according to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171931.aspx), there's a conversion support since SqlCe 3.5 that maps a nvarchar(16) in the value form of 'hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn' to a Time column.

Does anyone know if it's possible to use this with EF4.1 Code-First?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked article refers to Merge Replication, not data type mapping in EF. You must either use a string and convert to and from timespan in code, or use datetime.

Comment: I know that... But eventually it could work somehow. The technique you suggest is the workaround I've already made.